# update error handling in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a customer table in sqlserver which contains a `rowversion` field and I am incrementing it everytime I update the record, 
 I just have to check with

```
if(Customer.rowversion=@roeversion ) where customerID=@customerID
```

execute the update.

```
else RAISERROR('Update cannot be executed. There is a row version conflict.', 16, 1)
```

So have to now pass an out param from my c# code and return the error value. and also
- Get the Error Code for the statement just executed.

```
SELECT @ErrorCode=@@ERROR
```

So how should I return the value from SQLSERVER update query into my c# code so that I can display the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not already, you should have your database code in a stored procedure. The stored procedure would look something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_my_procedure
  @RowVersion    int ,
  @CustomerID    int ,
  ... additional fields here
  @ErrorCode     INT OUTPUT
AS
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM Customer
             WHERE RowVersion = @RowVersion
               AND CustomerID = @CustomerID)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE Customer
         SET ...
       WHERE RowVersion = @RowVersion
         AND CustomerID = @CustomerID

      SET @ErrorCode = 0
    END 
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @ErrorCode = 1234 -- Something meaningful to your app
    END
```

You should try to avoid raising errors whenever possible.

Then, assuming you have a stored procedure executed by a command:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

int ErrorCode = 0;

// Note that if you are not sure about your sp, you should test this for dbnull.value first
ErrorCode = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ErrorCode"].Value);
```

Comment: That is great news! Remember, if an answer solved or help you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the answer to let future visitors to the question know that it helped you.

Comment: I have one more thing to ask ... What should be the actual error code value to return  . should It be greater than 1200 or sql errors will return negative values so how to handle this ??

Comment: The error code can be any value that you want since it is not going through the SQL Server exception handling process. Our practice is to use negative numbers for errors and positive numbers for warnings, but you can choose any scheme that you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you're calling your sproc via ado.NET, then the SqlParameter you pass to the sproc would be set up like this:

```
SqlParameter P = new SqlParameter("Name of your column", SqlDbType.Int);
P.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

//call your sproc
int result = (int)P.Value;
```

**EDIT**

Since you're using Linq-to-SQL, adding this sproc into the methods sections should create a c# method signature for this sproc with the out parameter added **for you**.

Comment: I am calling my sproc through DBML db.usp_UpdateCustomer(CustomerID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Title, Active, SeeNote, UserId, RowVersion); So in this case how should I return .

Comment: OH!  Well if you're using linq-to-sql, then when you load the sproc into the method explorer, it should define it with an out parameter **for you**

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: @user1078389 - this link should go over that for you http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx